# Injecting dependencies to ViewControllers without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I have tested Typhoon using storyboards and plist integration, defining the dependencies in my assembly and worked as expected.
The dependencies on ViewControllerB are being properly injected for example when a push segue is performed from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB. I have seen that instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is swizzled to inject the properties.

However, I also have legacy code that don't use storyboard. It uses XIBs.
For example, LegacyViewControllerA pushes LegacyViewControllerB:

This is the code in LegacyViewControllerA:

```
LegacyViewControllerB *legacyVCB = [[LegacyViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"LegacyViewControllerB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
legacyVCB.paramOne = ...
legacyVCB.paramTwo = ...
[self.navigationController pushViewController:legacyVCB animated:YES];
```

This is the assembly:

```
- (LegacyViewControllerB *)legacyVCB
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[LegacyViewControllerB class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(apiClient)
                                                    with:[self myApiClient]];
    }];
}
```

Debugging LegacyViewControllerB's viewDidLoad, I expected to have the apiClient dependency already injected, but this is not the case. Why?

EDIT:

I have checked the sample application and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid knowing about the assembly and/or importing Typhoon in the ViewControllers. Actually I really liked the integration with storyboards because I was not making any reference to Typhoon.

So, let us say I don't have any storyboard, then the only way to get my ViewController injected would be to do the following?

```
MyApplicationAssembly *assembly = [[MyApplicationAssembly new] activate];
LegacyViewControllerB *legacyVCB = [assembly legacyVCB];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:legacyVCB animated:YES];
```

And had to modify my assembly to the following:

```
- (LegacyViewControllerB *)legacyVCB
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[LegacyViewControllerB class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                              [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithNibName:bundle:)
                                              parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                                                  [initializer injectParameterWith:@"LegacyViewControllerB"];
                                                  [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                              }];
                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(apiClient)
                                                    with:[self myApiClient]];
    }];
}
```

However this is not working for me either: `[assembly legacyVCB]` correctly returns an instance of LegacyViewControllerB with myApiClient injected, but when pushing it, LegacyViewControllerB's viewDidLoad does not have it injected. It seems that pushing it creates a new LegacyViewControllerB, because the memory address differs.
Why do you think this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typhoon hooks into UIStoryboard so that it works just like a regular storyboard with the added benefit that dependencies are injected, but as Typhoon is a dependency injection *container*, the normal way to obtain an injected instance is to ask Typhoon, via the assembly interface.

- Inject the Assembly into a storyboard view controller that wants to present a non-storyboard controller.
- Ask the assembly for a built instance.

Example:

```
UIViewController *controller = [assembly legacyVCB];
//Now push it into a container VC or subview
```

The [Typhoon sample application](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-Swift-Example) shows lots of examples of this.

Comment: Yes, its quite simple. I've answered that as a separate question for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487472/typhoon-obtain-a-typhoon-built-instance-of-a-class-without-depending-on-typhoo/31487498#31487498

Comment: Thanks, however, if I debug LegacyViewControllerB's viewDidLoad after `[self.navigationController pushViewController:legacyVCB animated:YES];` I see that it does not have the dependency (apiClient) injected. It seems that pushing creates a new LegacyViewControllerB. Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: If it helps to understand my problem, I can share with you a sample project in Github using storyboard (working as expected) and without storyboard (which is not injecting as expected).

Comment: Posted the problem in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507439/typhoon-not-injecting-property-without-storyboard