# Typhoon : Obtain a Typhoon-built instance of a class without depending on Typhoon

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

With Typhoon storyboard integration, all that is necessary for dependency injection is to use auto-injection macros or assembly methods on the class to be injected.

However elsewhere, its necessary to ask Typhoon to build an instance for us. Is there a way to obtain an instance, without having my class depend on Typhoon?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the spirit of dependency injection, Typhoon is designed so that its not necessary for any user classes to have a direct dependency on Typhoon.

Let's say you wish to obtain an instance of ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA within a Typhoon application. To do this, we create our definition for ViewControllerA such that the assembly is injected, and then ask the assembly to build an instance. This is [shown in the sample application](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon-Swift-Example) and [detailed in the user guide here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

The next step, if you wish to completely decouple your application classes from Typhoon, is to simply back your assemblies with a protocol, and inject that. In this way, all your application sees is a provider interface for the class view controller A needs in order to do its job. [Here's a tutorial on how to do this](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/backed-by-a-factory-protocol).

Comment: But Jasper, somehow ViewControllerA has to be injected with the assembly, in the sample I have seen that the only way to do this is to ViewControllerA be the root view controller injected to AppDelegate but if ViewControllerA is not the root view controller (e.g. it is just a view controller pushed by other view controller) then I would have to explicitly call [[MyAssembly new] activate] and then obtain ViewControllerB with its dependencies injected, am I right?

In wiki example, if I instantiate FriendListViewController using initWithNibName I believe the provider is not going to be injected.

Comment: Ordinarily you would **never** call `[[MyAssembly new] activate]` if you are already bootstrapping Typhoon using plist integration - that will create a new instance of Typhoon. . as for injecting the assembly - it can be injected anywhere, not just AppDelegate or RootController, as in the sample apps.

Comment: I've uploaded a simple project to demonstrate my issue here: https://github.com/fernandospr/TyphoonNoStoryboardExample
You will see ViewControllerC property "name" is not being injected. I'm bootstraping Typhoon using plist integration and not sure what I'm doing wrong, please can you check?

Comment: What part of the answer did you not understand? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I simply cannot inject the assembly nor anything to a view controller without using storyboards, please check the github small example if you can. You will see three view controllers and the assembly attempting to inject a property to one of them. It just does not work and cannot understand why.

Comment: I think you better post your code along with the question, as linking out to a separate project doesn't really match the StackOverflow format. The SO moderators like: a) Other users to benefit from the question in future b) reasonable amount of research and effort by those asking to solve the problem

Comment: Posted the problem in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507439/typhoon-not-injecting-property-without-storyboard